# How do I divide all margins but last to even out space?

Tags: jquery, css, width, margin

The problem is that there's going to be lots of different languages on our site with unknown dynamic text lengths. I need everything to be centered but without manually adding a right margin to every area like this. Would be great if it could do some type of jQuery calculation and make it so they look even like this every time but done automatically:
[Click here to see my CSS example](http://vt.mu/geoff/centerfilters/)

I tried modifying [this jQuery script I found](http://jsfiddle.net/UTaSg/) but I failed as you can see here jsfiddle.net/UTaSg/86/ 
This could work if it doesn't add the additional width to the last child (no space on right side of "Type: All Solo Band Group").

I'm not sure how to do this, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance for any help! Please use examples if possible.

There's always going to be these 4 filters in the 990px container and I want to keep 25px of space on the ends with all the different languages. So their text length will change slightly and I want the space in-between the 3 filter spaces to be equal.

Comment: Looks like a great use for flexbox (http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/qazmI) Too bad only chrome supports the new syntax currently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try simply sum the width if each text and substract it from width of the whole, dive by 3 and put it as right-margin to each element except the last one.

You can create generic plugin since this will work for any number of items are inside jQuery object with length, and you can get container using parent().

You can try this: http://jsfiddle.net/UTaSg/104/

Answer (score 0):

This may not be what you were hoping for, but if you truly won't know the width or quantity of filters for each column, then I think you should consider other possible designs.

This is a prime candidate for a drop-down list of filters. Yeah, it's not as cool, but it's functional.

Another option would be to set a fixed width on each column, then use `text-overflow: ellipsis;` to handle the text overflow. This would help visitors understand that there's more filters available, and you could seal the deal with an tiny arrow graphic that, when clicked, would slide over to reveal the additional filters. Something like this:

[image]

I know you were asking for a hammer and I gave you a banana, so my apologies this doesn't help.

Comment: There's always going to be these 4 filters in the 990px container and I want to keep 25px of space on the ends with all the different languages. So their text length will change slightly and I want the 3 in-between spaces to be equal.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to center the entire thing, you should use `width: 100%; margin: 0 auto;` on the container of the filters, which you're doing. If you want to have the same padding you don't need `.leftpositive, .leftnegative, .spacingforlanguage1`. You can simply do

```
.filter { padding-right: 2%; }
.filter:last-child { padding-right: 0; }
```

That way it's relative to the amount of space you have left, and the spacing will be relatively equal. You could also create a grid and set a maximum width for which any of the given filters could fit within the container (for example, the first filter gets a width of 33%, the second gets 25%, etc...). That's the best way to keep things even, especially for different browser widths and devices.

Comment: I understand what you mean but I cannot define widths cause we will never know them and it would be a pain to add them all over the site in areas like this. I need some type of auto calculation for the 3 in-between spaces to be equal.

Comment: That's the point of using percentages - you never have to calculate - they're all relative to the space you have, but they're all equal.